# Open PDF in WebView of Xamarin Windows Application

Tags: windows, pdf, xamarin, xamarin.forms, windows-8.1

Hi i want to open a local PDF file in my WebView of xamarin forms Windows 8.1 App.
I am able to open the PDF file if the path is an online source but am unable do to so using the local path.
Here is the code that I have used. Note:- Browser is the name of the WebView i have used.

```
string path  = "ms-appdata:///local/13/13.pdf";
Browser.Source = path;
```

Comment: Look at this page: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/display-pdf/

Comment: Hi @Joehl I already tried that method it doesn't render the PDF. Also this method is used if the file is in the assets folder. I am downloading the PDF in local folder(i.e. inside app data) first and then using it to display when the app is offline.